# How do I get theses values from this dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I'm using mastercard API. Link https://developer.mastercard.com/documentation/mastercom/6#api_transactions_debit_master_card_and_europe_dual_acquirer

I Have to get the value of these keys. (These are key from Dictionary List)

```
transactionSummaryList[0].authTransactionId
transactionSummaryList[0].clearingTransactionId
transactionSummaryList[0].singleMessageSummaryDetails.authTransaction.acquirerReferenceNumber
transactionSummaryList[0].singleMessageSummaryDetails.authTransaction.adviceReasonCode
...
```

My code so far

```
try
   {
      TransactionsDebitMasterCardAndEuropeDualAcquirer response = TransactionsDebitMasterCardAndEuropeDualAcquirer.searchForDebitMCMessageTransaction(transactionsValues);
      OutputTransaction outputTransaction = new OutputTransaction();

      foreach (Dictionary<String, Object> item in (List<Dictionary<String, Object>>)response["transactionSummaryList"])
           {
               TransactionSummary transactionSummary = new TransactionSummary();

               transactionSummary.authTransactionId = Out(item, "authTransactionId").ToString();
               transactionSummary.clearingTransactionId = Out(item, "clearingTransactionId").ToString();

               Object aux = Out(item, "singleMessageSummaryDetails");


               outputTransaction.transactionSummaryLists.Add(transactionSummary);

          }

     outputTransactions.Add(outputTransaction);

}

    public static Object Out(Dictionary<String, Object> response, String key)
    {
          return response[key];
    }
```

I'm facing trouble when i try to get values from **singleMessageSummaryDetails** Key.

All values that I want is inside Object aux, but i can't "reach" them.
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to get the value from that dictionary by key? (do you know the exact key you are trying to get)

Comment: Yeap. From these key i got it transactionSummaryList[0].authTransactionId and transactionSummaryList[0].clearingTransactionId. But the other I cant reach them. All values is inside this Object aux, idk how to get them.

Comment: So aux is an object that contains multiple dictionaries?

Comment: Hi Nolan Bradshaw, Thanks so much for try to help me, I already find my solution, check it out bellow. Keep helping this community, u r awesome guys. Bye. Have a great day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have case aux as an **Object**, therefore it doesn't know about any specific properties. [Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=netcore-3.1) is the base class that all other .NET classes inherit from.

If you want to get to a specific property they you'll need to cast your object to a specific type.

If you know the class type, then you can cast it directly using either;

`public static YourClass Out(Dictionary<String, YourClass > response, String key)` or `MyClass myClassInstance = (YourClass)myObject;`

If you don't know the type then you can use reflection. Its a bit more complicated but will be something like;

```
Type myType = myObject.GetType();
IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());

foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{
    object propValue = prop.GetValue(myObject, null);

    // Do something with propValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it!

To make this work, first I turn the mastercard answer in a JSON.

Them I put it simple and easy in my object (DeserializeObject).

```
 try
     {
        TransactionsDebitMasterCardAndEuropeDualAcquirer response = TransactionsDebitMasterCardAndEuropeDualAcquirer.searchForDebitMCMessageTransaction(transactionsValues);

        OutputTransaction outputTransaction = new OutputTransaction();

        var aux = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);

        outputTransaction = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OutputTransaction>(aux);

        outputTransactions.Add(outputTransaction);

     }
```

Thanks so much for your answer @Mark Cooper, helps me a lot.

Sry for my bad english.

Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad that has helped